# Prevent babel class properties plugin from overwriting my generated constructor

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin

**Overview**

I have written a babel plugin that adds a custom constructor to classes. I also use the `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin to support class properties. My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "./plugins/my-plugin.js",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  ]
}
```

I'm using `babel-core@7.2.2`, and `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.2.3`.

**The issue**

The class properties plugin overwrites my generated constructor. For example, given this test file:

```
// Source
class Test extends Base {
    // someProp = 'yay';
}
```

If I run *without* the class properties plugin, my constructor is inserted:

```
// Transpiled (no class props)
class Test extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);

        console.log('my special custom code');
    }
}
```

But if I uncomment `someProp` and enable the class properties plugin, my custom code is overwritten:

```
// Transpiled (with class props)
class Test extends Base {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        _defineProperty(this, "someProp", 'yay');
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter what order I list the plugins. Is this expected,  is there a way around it, or is this a bug?

I don't think the implementation of my plugin matters - but if it does, I can add more detail.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking for help in the Babel slack community, and they were able to help me fix this issue.

The problem was that I was using a different visitor in my implementation - I had visitors specified for `ClassDeclaration` and `ClassMethod`, but the visitor in the `plugin-proposal-class-properties` implementation was on `Class`. When I changed my code to work off of `Class`, and made sure mine ran first, the properties were added to my custom constructor as expected.